# Why aren't my PPA's showing up in the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: ppa, software-center, software-sources

When I add a PPA via Software Sources it normally would show up in the Ubuntu Software Center shortly after. But lately it seems that any PPA I add either won't show up, or takes days to. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: DId you update the package database (apt-get update)? Do they show up in Synaptic?

Comment: @RobinJ I think the package sources list is reloaded after adding a PPA: [video: Adding a PPA to Ubuntu using the Software Centre](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMxAtDlEHlo)

Comment: I've done apt-get update, and reloaded the cache using Software Sources. I've just found out that the PPA will only appear if I first install something from it using the terminal. This is strange.

Comment: @Alan: You can answer your question and mark it as answered. Don't worry, it is as compliant with AskUbuntu community policies

Comment: Hi Manish. I was hesitant to mark it as solved at first, I'm not sure if the question is really answered or not. Never the less, I will mark it as solved, and report this as a bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be partially resolved by installing something from the PPA via terminal first. Only then will you see the PPA appear in the Software Center.

Comment: I install all PPA's via terminal. It doesn't make a difference on my system. But the answer I provided above does.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the same bug that's been around for as long as I can remember then you need to run `sudo update-apt-xapian-index -f` to get the Software Center to update your added repo's. On further research, there are bug reports for this issue not showing added repo's and also for continuing to display repo's that have been removed. Either way, running this code will work for both. As of 13.04 this issue still persists.

Comment: saw it on 14.04